# What is the inverse of getnameinfo() for only string/binary conversions?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock

I can use `getnameinfo()` to convert a binary IP address from a `sockaddr_storage` to a string using flags `NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV` so no need to access the network.

If I want to convert the string back to `sockaddr_storage` there is `getaddrinfo()`, but that returns a different structure that results from querying the host on the network (and can return multiple addresses).  How do I do it without attempting to access the network?

I just want a `sockaddr_storage` to `string` conversion formatted in normal string notation, and that `string` back to `sockaddr_storage`.   Is there one that exists or options to `getaddrinfo()` to do what `getnameinfo()` can do?

TIA!!